# Stripe Ruby API: How to fetch the Connect Gross Volume

Tags: stripe-payments, ruby-stripe-api

In my Stripe Dashboard there's "Connect gross volume" that lists the volume that has gone through all Stripe Connect accounts associated with my account.  I would like to fetch this volume through the API, but cannot find a way to do so.

I've tried listing all reporting types but none seem to match (also accessible here https://stripe.com/docs/reports/report-types):

```
Stripe::Reporting::ReportType.list()
```

Is there another way to access it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the [Balance Report](https://stripe.com/docs/reports/balance) for each of Connected Account then combine the results, or easier, call [List PaymentIntent API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list), using [Stripe Account header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication) then combine the results.